# PHP or CGI - Convert .ico to gif or png or jpg?

Tags: php, c++, c, cgi, favicon

How do you convert a favicon.ico to a regular web-accessible graphics - gif, png, or jpg using PHP or C/C++/CGI?

- Are there methods that do not require ImageMagick?

Comment: is there a way other than using imagemagick?

Comment: Why is ImageMagick not allowed?

Comment: don't have imagemagick configured on my server - and tried 3+ hours to get it to install, but no dice... also, is there really no other way to do this other than with imagemagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server doesn't have Imagick installed, you can use GD (the hard way). You can do a pixel-by-pixel mapping by using the following format for sniffing the actual bitmap: http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-ico

Answer (score 2):

You cold use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Eigther you use [the native php extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) or you use a php `exec` command (for a commandline command) and then get the transformed image or as last option you use imagemagick as a server and request the new image from a webadress.

There are other commandline tools available, but they are not as powerfull and easy to use as imagemagick (i.e. GD);

Comment: once you have imagemagick, it is still not that straightforward to convert an arbitrary favico to png or gif... ImageMagick sometimes converts it to favicon, and sometimes favicon-0, favicon-1, ... there's no way to know which file is which

Comment: i guess this happens because there are several files inside the ico-file to be displayed in different contexts (i think other programms might have the same issues here). Did you try it yourself or do you just repeat what you found somewhere in the web?

Comment: if imagemagick is no choice for you then i'd give the mentioned Netpbm mentioned by "mu is too short" a try

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or one of its bindings.

Answer (score 0):

[Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) can handle all those formats and doesn't get nearly as much attention as it deserves.